# If $\int_t ^{t+1}f=1$, then showing $f(x+1)=f(x)$

Tags: real-analysis

Let $f$ be locally integrable on the real line and $\int_t ^{t+1}f$ is contstant for $t\in \mathbb{R}$, then $f\left(x+1\right)=f\left(x\right)$ almost everywhere.

I don't see how Lebesgue's Differentiation Theorem applies here since every integral we integrate over has length 1. I'm not sure if it makes any sense to speak of taking limits of shrinking balls about points on the line. I don't have much of an idea here. The only reason that I can see that this statement is true is by noting that if $f(x+\varepsilon)-f(x)$ is $\delta$, then the difference from $f(x+\varepsilon+1)-f(x+1)$ also must be $\delta$ since the integral of $f$ from $x+\varepsilon$ to $x+\varepsilon+1$ is the same as the integral from $x$ to $x+1$. Can I make this more rigorous?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To make your argument more rigorous, define $F(X) =\int_0^x f(t) dt$.

Observe that $F(X+1)=F(X)+1$ and that you can use Lebesgue DT for $F(x)$.